# How to remove default checkstyle in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I have a custom checkstyle.xml  imported and set as the default.  It works great.  I just upgraded to the newest version of checkstyle and now I have a warning on just about every line of code.  It looks like the warnings are coming from the two build in checkstyle xml's but they are not removable!

How can I disable these two checkstyle rule files so they stop bothering me?

Answer (score 2):

The built-in configurations are not removable and cannot be changed or edited. Instead, people are supposed to create their own configurations, which is just what you did.

There are a few things you can try:

- Make sure that your upgrade of the Checkstyle Eclipse plugin was performed correctly. Stop Eclipse. Check the *plugins* and *features* folders for contained folders called *edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugin.eclipse_*version. There should only be one such folder in *plugins* and one in *features*, both with the same version number. If there are more, delete the ones with the older version numbers. Restart Eclipse with the `-clean` option as first argument.
- Make sure that your custom Checkstyle configuration is still the default after the plugin upgrade.
- Check the Eclipse projects in your workspace and make sure that they do not have project-specific settings for Checkstyle. Right-click on project, select Properties, then Checkstyle. Make sure that the selected configuration is correct.
- Configuration names are case sensitive. This can be an issue if someone made a case mistake in the `.checkstyle` file located in each project's root directory. Or the configuration name was mistyped on import. This last point should result in different errors though (such as *configuration not found*).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Checkstyle locks in the 2 default rule sets.  Two options occur to me: 1) Edit the default rules to diable the conflicting rules (or all of them).  Or 2) delete the two xml files off the files system from the plugins/checkstyle (whatever the actual dir name is called).

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in the projects that you want check-style disabled for, edit your pom.xml change the check-style skip to true :

```
<properties>

    <!-- Checkstyle -->

    <checkstyle.skip>true</checkstyle.skip>

</properties>
```

you should also configure it like this:

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>validate</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                        <outputFileFormat>xml</outputFileFormat>
                        <failsOnError>false</failsOnError>
                        <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Checkstyle will still run, but will perform a no-op...